# How to set private key for Ethers Signer

Tags: nodejs, cryptography, ethers.js

I would like to invoke a smart contract function using [Ethers library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethers).
Since I have my own node I'm connecting using [RPC connection](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/getting-started/-%23-getting-started--connecting-rpc) and now I would like to invoke a `transfer` function (of an ERC20 contract), which according to the documentation requires me to use a signer:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(NODE_URL)
const signer = provider.getSigner()

// Read-Write; By connecting to a Signer, allows:
// - Everything from Read-Only (except as Signer, not anonymous)
// - Sending transactions for non-constant functions
const erc20_rw = new ethers.Contract(erc20ContractAddress, abi, signer)
const tx = await erc20_rw.transfer(targetAddress, amount)
```

My question is:
Where should I provide my private key? I mean - the [provider](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/providers/jsonrpc-provider/) requires me to give only a node url and the signer is provided by the provider.
I'm invoking a transfer, which defiantly should require me to provide a private key at some point. What am I missing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could simply replace the 2nd line in your code above and instead define the signer as follows:

```js
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(your_private_key_string, provider);
```

You could also define a signer from a mnemonic instead of a private key, as follows:

```js
const account = utils.HDNode.fromMnemonic(your_mnemonic_string).derivePath(`m/44'/60'/0'/0/${your_selected_account}`);

const signer = new Wallet(account, provider);
```

Where `your_selected_account` is the account index to use, starting from 0.

Note: make sure to use the right derivation path for you (Ledger, MEW, Metamask, ..etc).

Comment: Thanks of that. I now understand that I need to update the question:  I don't have a private key since the entity that holds the ERC20 token which I like to transfer is a smart-contract. How can I do that? Should the contract approve some wallet to do the transfer?

Comment: @forhas the contract will not have any ability to transfer or approve the transfer of any tokens that it holds by default, unless it had such ability implemented by the contract creator.

Answer (score 5):

```
const pKey = new ethers.Wallet.createRandom();
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(pKey, provider);
```

Comment: add some explanation as well

Answer (score 0):

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(URL);
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(WALLET_SECRET_KEY);
// connect the wallet to the provider
const signer = wallet.connect(provider);
```